# Google Sheets Dynamic URL pass to ImportRange() formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, dynamic-url

For simplicity, assume I would have a folder in Google Disk for each of **12 months**. So **12 folders**.
In each there are 2 Google Sheets. One is report sheet. Another is source sheet. So 2 sheets in a folder.

In a report sheet, **for example**, I use this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1", "Sheet1!B9:D9")) > 0, 1, "")
```

So it uses **IMPORTRANGE()** and access source sheet by its **URL** which is the source file access link. Report sheet take data from source sheet and formula do some calculations. This simple example just for simplicity.

---

Next, I need co create a **copy of this directory** (with 2 sheets inside) in Google Disk Drive. First folder was January. Then I create new Folder **February** with copies of two Google sheets inside. But formulas with **ImportRange()** still link to sheets in first "**January**" folder. So to fix it I need to change **URLS** in **importRange()** and change links to source file in February folder manually. In reality I have lots of sheets inside each month folder so doing it manually is impossible.

---

How to pass **dynamic URL** to **ImportRange()** formula in report sheet. So, if I create copy of this directory (January folder) in Google Disk for another month links inside new sheets link to a new generated source file (not initial one in previous folder)? Is it possible **to pass dynamic URL of a file within current directory** for a source file sheet for **importRange()** formula?

Comment: I am not aware of any Google Sheet formulas that can access file id of files inside a Google Drive folder. You need to use Apps Script and/or Drive API.

Comment: Regular functions do not have access to your Google Drive, you will need Apps Script for that.  Alternatively, to speed up it a bit, you set up a separate sheet with links to the source documents and pass them to IMPORTRANGE. There you can use file chips (type @ and select file) and in another cell extract url by `=A1.url`. This might be faster than opening all the files and copying their urls.  You will still need to grant access in the main document for IMPORTRANGE to work.